# Alignment issue in Firefox and IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, razor

On my header, i have a link and clicking on the link would open a menu, with list items below the link. It works fine in IE9,10 and chrome. But in Firefox and IE8, the link is moved to the left(though text-align is given as right) and menu is placed adjacent to it. I have spend my whole day on this issue, without any luck.

```
<div class="float-right">
<section>
<a> test@test.com </a>
<ul style="display: block;">
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
</ul>
<section>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.float-right {
    float: right;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7MWp/2/

Comment: it works fine for me in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/5pnm3/

Comment: @user24800288 - If you still find issues, please update to this in UL, <ul style="display: block;margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;">, i suspect the UL default margin and padding is moving the content to right.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j7MWp/2/

This is the fiddle. If you check in Firefox it is different from chrome and IE 10

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `<!DOCTYPE html>`? Sometimes this is only solution for IE.